# Trigger Function When Sent To Specific Address

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation

Is it possible to write a Token contract which will trigger a certain function when the tokens are sent to a specific Address? Like let's say, if you send 5 tokens to 0x12345... a specific function will be called that sends another 5 tokens to 0x98765... This is just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token contract has a `transfer` function that does the token sending. You can modify the token contract to check `if(recipient == 0x12345...)` and then add your code to send.